# Using laravel SSH to upload files to another server

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, upload

Revised:

I have an uploaded file that I would like to move to my other server for processing with another application. I thought the best way would be to use SSH built into Laravel however, it's proven to be a headache.

In my configuration file (remote.php), I've successfully set up my connection to my other server using SSH keys. I tested this by running

```
SSH::run(['cd /var/www/html', 'ls'], function($line) {

    echo $line . PHP_EOL;    

});
```

and it gave me a list of files in `/var/www/html/` on my remote server. All seems good, right?

Now I want to use `SSH::put()` to upload my uploaded file to the remote server. I used:

`SSH::put($file->getRealPath(), '/var/www/html/uploads');`

Guess what? It ran without an error so I assumed it was uploaded successfully. When I checked that directory on the remote server, it was blank. I've tried to set file permissions to 777 on `/var/www/html/uploads` to see if it was a permission issue, same thing--nothing.

I also tried using `SSH::get()` to download a file from my remote server and it ran successfully.

Here's a dump on `$file->getRealPath()`:

`string(14) "/tmp/phpikt2mg"`

Both machines are running Centos and have their public keys registered on both ends.

Comment: I think you need `SSH::into($connectionName)->put(...)`

Comment: I've tried that as well, still no good.

Comment: The docs suggest that passing that UploadedFile object won't work and you'll need to call `->getRealPath()`, so you're supplying the local path to the file (not the object), and the remote path where you want it stored.

Comment: Tried that and nothing, I ran an example command to create a file and SSH is working.

Comment: I'm doing this on my localhost which is running Windows

Comment: Still have no solved this issue, I've uploaded it to my secondary centos server and still no errors or anything. It runs successfully put I don't see the uploaded file on the server it "uploaded" to. Please help.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey anymore suggestions? Like I said I am torn right now and I need to be able to upload this file to my other server.

Comment: Maybe do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3)` and post the output here. Well post it in pastebin.com and post a link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Fxdtuz9s

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little bit late, but just faced the same problem and finally found the reason of failure! So it could save some minutes to others.

You should use full path with filename as a second parameter instead of just a path to folder. For this question it should be

```
SSH::put($file->getRealPath(), '/var/www/html/uploads/' . $file->getFilename());
```

Comment: Is this applicable to laravel 5.4 ?

Comment: No 5.4 has envoy runner